# Is it possible to do File deployment in SSIS 2014

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

I have been doing file deployment and database deployment in sql server 2008.I have gone through the ssis(on sql 2014) and seen only catalogue based deployment.
Just wondering ,is there file deployment still available in ssis 2014.

can not find any file deployment option in deployment wizard.

There is an option called convert to package deployment.Does it mean the file deployment is only available under the package deployment option .

If i select the "Convert to package deployment" option,then the project deployment is not going to work in the future!

Also,Is there any concept of configuration in ssis 2014!
In ssis 2008 ,we have a file called configuration file and it contains all the 
connection information.After the package deployment,we can change all the package connection information in this single file ,instead of opening and doing it in multiple files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two deployment models available to SSIS from the 2012 release going forward: Project Deployment Model (new, default) and Package Deployment Model (classic).

### Which deployment model am I using?

The easiest way is to look at Solution Explorer. If you see a node under there specifying Project.params, then you are in the Project Deployment Model (left half of the image). Otherwise, you should see a "Data Sources" folder along with the project title's giant hint `(package deployment model)` (right half of the image)

[image]

### Is File Deployment still a thing?

Package Deployment Model allows you to keep your process if you like your process. Happy deploying to the file system? Great, keep it up. Enjoy explicitly turning on logging and configuration - it's all yours. Just convert to the package deployment model and it's all there.